# Cordova_Plugins.js Not Found

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins, cordova-plugins

I am running Cordova 2.9.1 for iOS. When I run my app in the browser, the console says I am missing cordova_plugins.js.

What is that? How do I get it?

Is that the reason none of my plugins are working at all?

Thanks!

Comment: This is not possible. Cordova apps need to be run in emulators or devices. This is because `cordova.js` and `cordova_plugins.js` require native code to interface with and no native code will run in a browser.

Comment: i mean when i run my index.html file

Comment: Sorry, here is a more complete answer: The cordova js files would not work in a browser if you were able to find them and include them in your files. When you compile (build) your cordova application the framework adds the correct version of the cordova.js and cordova_plugins.js for the platform being built. The cordova apis are tied to native code, so they cannot run in a browser, even if you are just loading your index.html. If you need to test this in a browser, exclude all the cordova intems, as they wouldn't work even if you did include them.

Comment: Thanks. However, even when I run on my mobile device, it says that CDV Plugin PushPlugin cannot be found in the console on XCode. Do you know why this would be occuring? I have installed it property...

Comment: I'm actually getting that error while running it in an android emulator (using chrome inspector to view the console). And there is no `cordova_plugins.js` file in my www.

Comment: @user3630775 - Did you manage to find a solution to this issue? I am now having this problem since updating my dev environment to the latest software

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the "browser" platform to your Cordova project?

> cordova platform add browser

After which, you need to build the Cordova project:

> cordova build browser

You'll notice the platforms/browser/www folder exists and contains a cordova_plugins.js file.

At this point, you need to "serve" files to your web browser from that folder (to test your app using a web browser). I use Grunt and the NodeStatic task for this purpose.

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions, take care.

Comment: I experienced the same problem, but when trying to build an Ionic IOS app that would not load on a device but would "ionic serve".  cordova_plugins.js was not in the /platforms/ios/www folder as I expected, until I ran "ionic cordova add browser" and now the IOS app works on an Ipad since the cordova_plugins.js is now in the ios/www folder.  I never would have expected this to work, as I assumed that ios and browser were independent, but not so.  Thanks for the tip.